# How much will the transactionlog grow when making a delete given number of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table in sql server that has the following data from `exec sp_spaceused`

```
rows        reserved           data               index_size         unused
182515      16721960 KB        16563768 KB        14920 KB           143272 KB
```

I want to delete `38693` rows. Is this the right way to calculate in a rough estimate how much the transaction log can increase in this delete?

`(38693/182515)*16721960 KB` at most? `3.544 GB`

Can any one help my please.

Comment: see if this helps https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25531/how-can-i-get-the-actual-data-size-per-row-in-a-sql-server-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your estimate of (16 GB data / 182,515 rows) X 38,693 rows looks like a reasonable estimate.

Another estimate is to take the average row size and multiply that times the number of rows that you want to delete.

For example, this query will get you the average record size of a clustered table.  It may take a while to return for huge tables:

```
select avg_record_size_in_bytes * 38693 / 1024.0 as [MB]
from sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(db_id(), object_id('MyTable'), 1, 0, 'Sampled')
```

To be extra sure, you could restore a backup of the database on a test server and measure the effect of the deletion there.